# Enable HelpPages when using OWIN Katana

Tags: asp.net, owin, katana, asp.net-web-api-helppages

I can get the help pages to render using the traditional asp.net engine, but how can I get the same thing when hosting the Web API service on OWIN/katana.

I tried adding `HelpPageConfig.Register(config);` to `class Startup` to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the following code inside the Configure() method in  Startup.cs?

```
AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
```

Comment: Seems like it would not address the issue of getting the help page to show. I am not really looking to register areas, I want the /help uri to work.

Comment: moreover, it might also yield  "System.InvalidOperationException: This method cannot be called during the application's pre-start initialization phase."